# Problemas com Insert SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Eu estou procurando uma solução para resolver meu problema. Quando eu peço 2 itens do mesmo tipo no meu site ele insere 2 vezes o mesmo item. Eu já tentei criar uma TRIGGER com AFTER INSERT para verificar se já existe aquele número de pedido mas sem sucesso

Eu já tentei: `INSERT INTO Lojas.dbo.ComprasSucc (Usuario,Codigo_Produto,Quantidade,Numero_Pedido,Produto_Name,Data) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,GETDATE()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Numero_Pedido=Numero_Pedido+1`

no código PHP do meu site também mas ele não consegue enviar.

Eu gostaria de verificar se já existe um número de pedido igual dentro da tabela antes de inserir. Tentei: `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT Numero_Pedido FROM ComprasSucc WHERE Numero_Pedido = @Numero_Pedido)`

Mas não consegui fazer com que ele verificasse se já existia realmente.
Não tenho conhecimento o bastante em SQL Server.

Os números de pedidos que são enviados para o banco de dados são random (Aleatórios).

também já tentei MAX(ID) mas se fizer 2 pedidos diferentes ao mesmo tempo ele só realiza o último.

Comment: Já pensou em definir `Numero_Pedido` como chave primária na tabela `ComprasSucc`?

Comment: Só pode uma e a minha tabela já tem uma principal ;(

Comment: Neste caso a constraint UNIQUE solucionará.

Comment: Tentei mas quando faço 2 compra no mesmo carrinho ele gera o mesmo ID do Numero do Pedido então é enviado apenas 1

Comment: Tudo indica que este é um problema de sua aplicação e não do banco de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo enunciado compreendi que o problema está na geração do número de pedido, sendo que para pedidos diferentes foi utilizado o mesmo número de pedido.

Uma solução é utilizar um gerador de números de pedidos, conforme detalhado no artigo “[Geração de sequências numéricas](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2019/04/21/geracao-de-sequencias-numericas/)”. Uma forma de implementar é através de [SEQUENCE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sequence-numbers/sequence-numbers?view=sqlallproducts-allversions), que é um objeto definido pelo usuário que gera uma sequência de valores numéricos de acordo com a especificação com a qual a sequência foi criada. Ela pode ser crescente ou decrescente, com intervalo definido, e pode também repetir a sequência, em ciclos.

Outra forma de implementação é a utilização de uma tabela de sequências, que é a utilização de tabela auxiliar para armazenar qual o último valor gerado da sequência. Cria-se um procedimento específico para obter o próximo número de pedido e ele deve ser acionado uma única vez para cada pedido, sendo então o mesmo número repetido para cada item do mesmo pedido.

Eis um exemplo:

```
-- código #2.15
-- próximo valor disponível
declare @Prox_Valor int;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

EXECUTE dbo.GetSequence 
     @nome_seq= 'dbo.Pessoa.ID_Pessoa',
     @valor = @Prox_Valor output;

INSERT into dbo.Pessoa (ID_Pessoa, Nome_Pessoa)
  values (@Prox_Valor, 'Paulo Antunes');

COMMIT;
go
```

Como consta no capítulo “Análise dos métodos” do artigo que citei, a pior implementação é a do tipo "MAX (coluna) +1", pois ela não está imune à [concorrência de processos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concorr%C3%AAncia_(ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)).

O assunto geração de chaves numéricas é extenso mas está bem explicado no artigo “[Geração de sequências numéricas](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2019/04/21/geracao-de-sequencias-numericas/)”. A leitura atenta dele te indicará caminhos para resolver o seu problema atual.